# Can i break line inside a <sub> tag?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display a formula. The denominator is long in text and I wanted to break line. Can someone please help?

My current code:

```
<p>
   <sup>Active Subscribers</sup>
   <span style="font-size:30px;">/</span>
   <sub>Total Number of Subscribers</sub>
</p>
```

My result is: Active Subscribers/Total Number of Subscribers

What I want:

```
           Active Subscribers/Total Number 

                              of Subscribers
```

But with sup and sub tags. Sorry I don't know WHy I am not able to add images.

Here is a codepen link: https://codepen.io/rashmeereddy25/pen/wZBQmx

Comment: Have you considered using something that's more or less designed for this: [MathML](https://www.w3.org/Math/)? Also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Authoring

Comment: Just want to point out that you are commenting incorrectly in your Codepen link.  In HTML, if you want to add notes, you put your text in between a `<!--` and a `-->`.  Example: `<!-- this is a comment -->`

Comment: `sup` and `sub`  are `inline` elements. If you use `sub { display: inline-block }` then you get something better but it may not be enough. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EJaOry

Comment: please see my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the br tag and add the css rules:

`sub{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
}`

```css
sub{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <sup>Active Subscribers</sup>
  <span style="font-size:30px;">/</span>
  <sub>Total Number of Subscribers</sub>
</p> 

When I add a br tag:

<p>
  <sup>Active Subscribers</sup>
  <span style="font-size:30px;">/</span>
  <sub>Total Number of Subscribers</sub>
</p> 

I need the "of Subscribers" under "Total Number"
```

Comment: You say _"When I add a br tag"_ but your second example _doesn't have_ a br tag. It's the `width 80px` that is getting the Total Number to wrap, and as you see it wraps in the first case too. Setting the width makes this work for _only **this** case_ -- if your text were different you'd have to pick a different width. Adding in the `<br>` tag (which you say you do, but you don't) would work without having to set the width.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use css grid like this:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item"><sup>Active Subscribers</sup>
    <span style="font-size:30px;">/</span>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <sub class="tete">Total Number <br> of Subscribers</sub>        
  </div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**furas** was not far...

see => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

```css
sub {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <sup>Active Subscribers</sup>
  <span style="font-size:30px;">/</span>
  <sub>Total Number <br> of Subscribers</sub>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, MathML can do this pretty easily: https://jsfiddle.net/2gjsnxqd/

```
<math>
    <mfrac>
        <mi>Active Subscribers</mi>
        <mi>Total Number of Subscribers</mi>
    </mfrac>
</math>
```

Of course, support isn't what it should be, given MathML is part of the HTML standard: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mathml.

Here's what I see, since I use Firefox as my primary browser:

[image: A page snippet showing rendered MathML formula]

If you decide to go this route in the future, I'd start here: [Daniel I. Scully - A Beginner's Guide to MathML](http://danielscully.co.uk/projects/mathml-guide/)